# array_contains equivalent for JSON in HiveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

HiveQL offers an array_contains() function for its array datatype, and also offers json support.

However, the get_json_object() function does not return an array datatype when fetching a json array, meaning the array_contains() function cannot be used on the resulting json_array.

What is the best way to mimic the array_contains() functionality for a json array in HiveQL?

As a concrete example, I want the following to return true:

array_contains_mimic(get_json_object({"array":["one", "two"]}, '$.array'), "one")

Answer (score 4):

The Brickhouse library ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) has expanded UDFs for processing JSON.

The brickhouse UDF "json_split" converts JSON text corresponding to an array, and convert it to a Hive array. ie.   You could implement what you need with

```
array_contain( json_split( get_json_object('{"array":["one"],"two"]}', '$.array'), 'one')
```

Brickhouse also allows you to serialize and deserialize arbitrary Hive structures, so you can do more complex operations.

With from_json, your expression would be

```
array_contains( map_index( from_json( str, map( "string", array("string"))),"array"),"one)
```